# Vuze downloading something else?

Tags: download, bittorrent, utorrent, vuze

While downloading a video and few other files along with it I found following condition
[image]

Why it is showing nothing in front of 1.4 GB while total downloaded data is 2.16 MB and also speed in front of 1.4 GB is less than actual download speed why is so? 
Is there something hidden downloading going on or it is the way Vuze work?

Comment: The total downloaded includes discarded data. If it downloads a 2MB chunk and it fails validation, it still counts against the total data, but was not applied to the video file's downloaded amount.

Comment: and what about speed difference?

Comment: (Went ahead and just rolled it into an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total downloaded includes discarded data. If it downloads a 2MB chunk and it fails validation, it still counts against the total data, but was not applied to the video file's downloaded amount.

The speed difference is usually protocol overhead. Only actual file data transfer is attributed to the video file, while the total includes that plus all the data used to communicate with other peers about what chunks are available, who has which chunks, etc.